# Inputting a smaller size vector to a Verilog Module

Tags: vector, input, size, verilog

I was wondering what would happen if I created a module with a certain size vector declaration as an input, and then fed it a smaller sized vector while instantiating it later. For example, say I create a module like so:

```
module example(input, ....);
  input[15:0] input;
  ...
  endmodule
```

And then I instantiate it later, but pass it a smaller vector size input like so:

```
wire[11:0] foo;
example bar(foo, ....);
```

So what happens to `input` in this case? Since `input` is supposed to be 16 bits, does it just zero pad `foo` on the left?

Comment: "input" in your example is a verilog keyword and it cannot be used as variable name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default value of wire is '`Z'(High-Impedance)`. Since 4 bits of the inputs are not connected remaining input bits `[12:15]` takes the default value in condition all the remaining bits connected are properly driving the input. Generally to eliminate these kind of errors in a larger RTL designs running any static tool on the code is recommended.